# Screen resolution messed up after update from windows update on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, display, windows-update, resolution

Hello i installed some updates for windows 7 from windows update yesterday and it completely messed up my screen resolution for some reason.

I have always had 1920x1080 working fine without problems, but now it shows 1920x1080 as 1280x1024 at maximum.
I have tried applying different resolutions and running windows repair but nothing helps.

Comment: I tried restoring to a point before the update happened, but still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

1. Update your monitor driver.
2. Update your video card driver.

Comment: I have the latest drivers for both.

Comment: Are you using DVI/HDMI or VGA as monitor input?